# Java (LibGDX) Collision between 2 Arraylist, Only last Object collides

Tags: java, android, arraylist, libgdx, collision

Im Developing an App / a  Game.

**I try to check the collision between EVERY OBJECT from one Arraylist and EVERY OBJECT from another Arraylist!**

The Problem is that with my code the collision only works for the last Object!

Here is my Code *(Names changed)*:

```
for (Object1Class objects1 : Object1Arraylist) for (Object2Class objects2 : Object2Arraylist) {         
        if (Intersector.overlaps(objects1.getCollisionRec(), object2.getCollisionRec())) {
            objects1.attack();
            // And Some unimportant Methods for now
        } else {
            objects1.move();
        }
        if (Intersector.overlaps(objects2.getCollisionRec(), objects1.getCollisionRec())) {
            objects2.attack();
            // And Some unimportant Methods for now
        } else {
            objects2.move();
        }
    }
```

The ".getCollisionRec()" method gets the Rectangle that is created in the Class of the Object (Object1Class & Obect2Class) and moves on top of the  objects.

Here is the part of classes where the Rectangle is created:

> CollisionRec = new Rectangle();
>
> CollisionRec.set(position.x + 20, position.y + 30, 15, 30);

and simply

> public Rectangle getCollisionRec() {
>           return CollisionRec;
>       }

I really don't know what i should change so that the collision works and how i can delete the object after the collision :/

Comment: You've asked several questions here, and you haven't provided enough information to get an answer to any of them. I suggest taking your problems one at a time and posting an (MCVE)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] for each.

Comment: thanks! Question is updated now

Comment: I still don't see an MCVE.